# Criteria for retriving data involving multiple joins

Tags: hibernate, criteria, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have four tables with sample data related with eachother as below

**Employee**

```
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME
---------------
101   |John
```

**EmployeeDtl**

```
EMP_DTL_ID  |EMP_SKILLS |EMP_ID
-----------------------------------
1001        |Java       |101
1002        |SQL        |101
```

**EmpDeptDtl**

```
EMP_DTL_ID  |DEPT_ID
--------------------
1001        |22
1002        |33
```

**Dept**

```
DEPT_ID |DEPT_NAME
----------------------
22      |XYZ
33      |PQR
```

Below are my corresponding pojos

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name="EMP_ID")
   private Long empId;

   @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
   private String empName;

   //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmployeeDtl 
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<EmployeeDtl> empDtls;


@Entity
@Table(name="EMP_DTL")
public class EmployeeDtl {

   @Id
   @Column(name="EMP_DTL_ID")
   private Long empDtlId;

   @Column(name="EMP_GRP")
   private String employeeGrp;


   //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee 
    @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")
   private Employee employee;

    @Column(name="EMP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Long empId;

   //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmpDeptDtl
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="id.empDtlId", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<EmpDeptDtl> empDeptDtls;



@Entity
public class EmpDeptDtl {

   @EmbeddedId
   private EmpDeptDtlPK id;

   @Column(name="EMP_DTL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Long empDtlId;

   //bi-directional many-to-one association to Dept
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Dept deptId;



@Embeddable
public class EmpDeptDtlPK implements Serializable {
   //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name="DEPT_ID")
   private Long deptId;

   //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmpDeptDtl
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="EMP_DTL_ID")
   private EmployeeDtl employeeDtl;


@Entity
public class Dept  {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
   private Long deptId;

   @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
   private String deptName;

        // bi-directional many-to-one association to EmpDeptDtl 
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deptId")
   private Set<EmpDeptDtl> empDeptDtls;
```

Now, **Can anyone suggest me on how to retrieve the list of Dept records for the given EMP_ID using CRITERIA**. In the above sample data given, for the EMP_ID=101, the dept records with dept_ids 22 and 33 should be returned.

I got the solution using Named query and native SQl query. But I couln't get it through the hibernate CRITERIA. Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks
Harish

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct translation from .net to java and I am not sure if the syntax is correct but you can wokr around it ( not sure, cos from the looks of it you dont seem to know a lot abt criteria, I would suggest read abt it as this is one of the easiest queries to write)

```
session.createCriteria(Employee.class,"emp")
.createAlias("emp.empDtls","empDetail")
.createAlias("empDetail.empDeptDtls","empDetail")
.createAlias("empDetail.deptId","dept")
.add(Restrictions.Eq("emp.empId", 101))
.setProjection(projections.property("dept.deptId"))
.toList<long>();
```

The answer doesnt necessarily mean I agree with your data model.. Also some of the member names could be changed to denote what they really represent..

Comment: But does this return back the list of Dept objects? Because, I need to retrieve the list of Dept records for the given EMP_ID in the Employee table

Comment: you need to modify your projection for that!

Comment: Can you please let me know on how to do that?